# Which backgroundcolor does the Material Design 3 Navigation bar have in Google Apps?

Tags: material-design, google-apps, material-design-3

According to the [navigation bar documentation in Material Design 3](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/), the navigation bar has the background color `md.sys.color.surface`.

I tried this in one app, but the Google Apps (Play Store, Photos, ...) seem to use a different color. Does anyone know what color Google uses here?

[image: Light mode (Google Play Store on the right)]
[image: Dark mode (Google Play Store on the right)]

In Flutter, surface is implemented like this:

```dart
final Color surface = Color(neutrals.get(dark ? 10 : 99));
```

Comment: If you want to hardcode the color, then a good suggestion would be to take a screen shot from the android phone and use the color grab android app to get the hex values for a specific pixel area. From there, you can use those hex values as you like in your app.
But, I can't help you if you want to dynamically change your app's color

Answer (score 2):

There is simple but not that obvious solution

```kotlin
val navigationBarElevation = NavigationBarDefaults.Elevation
systemUiController.setNavigationBarColor(color = colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(navigationBarElevation))
```

A NavigationBar itself uses a `surface` color and is elevated by some default value. You can access the latter value this way: `NavigationBarDefaults.Elevation`. Knowing this you should use an extension function `ColorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation()`, which guarantees you the required color. Note that if you use a default `ColorScheme`, change `colorScheme` to `MaterialTheme.colorScheme`

Answer (score 0):

It is also the `surface` color, but they configured other colors for `surface`. In this case, it is `#FFFFFFFF` for Light mode and `#FF000000` for dark mode.

Comment: The dynamic colors of Material You are somehow integrated into the color scheme. In the question, I already assumed that it is not simply the surface color.
As far as I understand your answer the following should work:
`const Color(0xffffffff).harmonizeWith(Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface)`
However, this is even further from the color in Google Apps compared to surface.